# Typescript inheritance and promises: how to get resolved promise in the sub class

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, inheritance

I have three classes the base class `Animal` and the `Cat` sub class and the App class:

The app class calls the `Animal` class which fetches the data, the `Cat` class should filter the data and get the data only relevant to the `Cat` data.

App.ts

Resolves the promise and should get cats but gets undefined because the sub class is constructed before the promise is resolved;

```
this._cats = new Cats();
this._cats.fetchAnimalData().then(() => {
     this._cats.getCats(); // returns undefined
});
```

Animal.ts
Fetches Animal data

```
    private async _setAnimalsDataContract(): Promise<[]> {
        return await ...;
    }
    public getAnimalData() {
        return this._animalData;
    }
    public setAnimalData(data) {
        this._animalData = data;
    }
    public fetchAnimalData() : Promise<void> {
        return this._animalDataPromise
                .then((dataSet: IAnimal;[]) => {
                   this._setAnimalData(dataSet);
                }).catch(() => {
                    throw new Error('...');
                });
   }
```

Cat.ts
getAnimalData is undefined because the base class didint finish fetching

```
export default class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this._catData = (this._formatCatData(this.getAnimalData()));
    }
    getCats() {
       return this._catData;
    }
}
```

I could of course instantiate Animal class wait until promise is resolved then instantiate the Cat class inside `then` but it would not make sense to do class extension at all then.

**How to get base class resolved promise data inside the sub class when its finished ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the result of a promise to a variable and accessing it somewhere else is dangerous, as you might access it before the promise resolved and then it doesn't work. Instead just work with the promise:

```
 class Animal {
   get data() {
      return this._promise || (this._promise = fetchAnimalData());
   }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
 get cats() {
   return this.data.then(data => /*...*/);
 }
}

const cat = new Cat();
cat.cats.then(console.log);
```

But I don't know why you need a class at all...

Comment: ok this looks good but how do I assign `cat.cats.then` to an object or variable ?

Comment: @guedrius just don't.

Comment: Im sorry for not being specific enough in the description but i didin't want it to be  too long. different classes are returning statistics on different "animal" and will be assigned to chart object, where each getter return datasets that will become lines in the chart. Would in that case my approach be better ? However I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @giedrius nope, and I would even doubt that you need classes at all. You should build the chart when the promise resolved